# Statistical Question for Probability for Choosing Cards

Tags: statistics

If I have a deck of 50 cards with 8 out of the 50 cards being the same card, what is the probability that if I reveal the top 6 cards that I will reveal at least one of the 8 cards that were the same?

Comment: For questions like this, it’s usually easiest to find the probability that *none* of the revealed cards is one of the special ones and subtract that from $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of ways that the top six cards can be selected from the cards that are not the same is $C^{42}_{6}$. The total number of ways that the top six cards could be selected is $C^{50}_{6}$.

Comment: What would the probability be though?

Comment: You just need to divide

Comment: (42 choose 6) divided by (50 choose 6) or 1- (42 choose 6) divided by (50 choose 6)?

Comment: The fact that you asked that question means that you do understand what you need to do.

Comment: Assume the deck is well shuffled. In R statistical software, the probability of choosing _none_ of the 8 special cards is `choose(42,6)/choose(50,6)`, which returns `0.3301167`. Alternatively, this is a 'hypergeometric' probability with 8 'red' items and 42 non-red items in the population, and asking for the probability that no red items are selected among 6 sampled without replacement: the code
`dhyper(0, 8, 42, 6)` also returns `0.3301167`.

Comment: @BruceET it originally asked p(x>=1) but you compute p(x=0). Why is 1 not subtracted from it ?

Comment: @Brandon: (1) following approaches of 'amd', and of 'Unwisdom' to which the Comment is attached. (2) Also, carefully italicized _none_ in one place and said 'no red' in another.

Answer (score 1):

(42 choose 6) divided by (50 choose 6) = .669 ended up being the correct answer.  I asked a close friend and there are apparently 3 ways to do it.

1: 1- (42 choose 6) divided by (50 choose 6)

2: 1 - (42/50)(41/49)(40/48)(39/47)(38/46)(37/45)

3: 1 - 1/e